# Query is working but not getting the right results. Is there any alternate which I can use?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying inner join in Darby Query. It's working fine, but missing some results when fetching data from the database of two tables. When I try with more data it's giving some right results, but not all of the results are right.

Table X and Y data.

Table X:

```
A       B       Time
5509    7015    11:19:40
9506    7072    11:19:43
```

Table Y:

```
A       B       Time
7072    9506    11:19:43
6247    669     11:19:45
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT orig.A, orig.B, orig.TIME
from  X orig INNER JOIN
      (SELECT A, B, TIME
       from X
      ) t1 
      ON t1.B = orig.A and t1.TIME = orig.TIME UNION ALL
SELECT orig.A, orig.B, orig.TIME
from  Y orig INNER JOIN
      (SELECT A, B, TIME
       from Y
      ) t1
      ON t1.B = orig.A and t1.TIME = orig.TIME
ORDER BY TIME
```

The query returns no result.

Required result:

```
A       B       Time
9506    7072    11:19:43
7072    9506    11:19:43
```

Comment: what is the logic you are trying to achieve? Rows that match X.A with Y.B and rows that match X.B with Y.A ?

Comment: my logic i want to add both table data then want to find row  column A values match with column b with same time

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select x.A, x.B, x.TIME
from x
where exists (select 1 from y where y.time = x.time)
union all
select y.A, y.B, y.TIME
from y
where exists (select 1 from x where x.time = y.time);
```

If this returns no rows, then probably the times are slightly different.  You might replace the `=` with an expression such as:

```
y.time > x.time - interval 1 second and
y.time < x.time + interval 1 second
```

Comment: working for two table not working with more then two table

Comment: @jais . . . This question is about 2 tables, so it has been answered.  If you have another question about more than two tables, then ask it as a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.